# MySQLi and PDO Connection in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, mysqli

I was a MySQL PHP coder, but then I realized that is vulnerable to SQL Injections and mysqli_* functions are deprecated, I decided to move on to some other way. I was wondering what is better, MySQLi or PDO?

- What is the Most Secure?
- What is quick in loading up data?
- What is not vulnerable/least vulnerable to SQL Injections?
- What is most popular and is preferred by the community?

I need help with these 4 questions and I am here to get them answered. I hope I will find high quality answers.

Comment: MySQL is not deprecated , mysql_* functions are deprecated.

Comment: Yeah, still they are deprecated and people recommend to move on to either MySQLi or PDO. Let me fix my post.

Comment: The security lies in how yu write the code to handle you input and display output. You need to filter input and escape output for security and always use the multilevel security. Never forget the human factor. I will definatley go for PDO , and PDo prepared statements

Answer (score -2, accepted):

All three APIs are equally safe, quick and invulnerable.

PDO is preferred by the community because it's being a semi-DAL (Database Access Library) already, while both mysqli and mysql are just raw APIs that shouldn't be used as is but only as a build material for such a library. And because community has no desire/education/habit to create one out of two latter APIs, PDO is left as the only choice.

As an old school programmer you need to know only two things

- Every variable should never go into query directly but via placeholder only
- unlike mysql, PDO require a connection variable to be always available. Means you need to learn what variable scope is and how to access a global variable.

Comment: Well MySQLi prepared statement's is something that is actually safe and agreed, the down voters should comment before down voting.

Comment: Everything is safe if you know what are you doing. While no gospel like "XXX is safe" can really secure your application.